# Send email to requestors/submitters from an InfoPath 2010 Filler form

Tags: infopath, email

I have created a filler form using InfoPath 2010. The form sends data to a SharePoint form library. I want a "receipt" sent to requestors/submitters confirming their data has been accepted. Workflow is not an option since many people within the organization will be submitting the InfoPath form. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Info path can send data to an email address directly. You can create a new submission rule that will email individuals after the form is saved to sharepoint.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: So how does this answer the OPs question?